# Best way to modify session timeout for some pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

For you what is the best way to do that?
I would like that all the pages of my app have timeout of 20 minutes but 4. I would like these 4 pages have 60 minutes timeout..

What is the best way?Have I to set the Session.timeout in the constructor of the pages? Is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Are these pages all in one directory? By themselves?

Comment: These pages are in the same dir but mixed with others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom base page (that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page), set the session timeout in the Page_Init handler, and then set those four pages to inherit from your custom base page.  That gives you one place to manage the session timeout value.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking put instructions in the constructor, but that was a bad idea, OnInit event is best one! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this through web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <sessionState timeout="20"/>
  <location path="Page1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Page2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Page3.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the idle timeout for the application pool as well:

http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/02/20/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net.aspx

According to the docs, you can set the timeout at anytime.   Of course it has to be while during a request to the server!  :-)

You could implement a custom Page attribute, like:

```
using System;
System.Web.SessionState;

public class TimeoutControlPage: System.Web.UI.Page {
    public int Timeout {
        get { return Session.Timeout; }    
        set { Session.Timeout = value; }
   }
```

}

and then save the below page as "test.aspx":

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Timeout="60"  Inherits="TimeoutControlPage" %>

<html>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```