# asp.net site session timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I have created asp.net site with quartz scheduler. All the job is running in background and there is no other activity on the site.

Quartz scheduler scheduled for 24 hours duration gap on daily basis,
the job in this scheduler taking time of 7 to 8 hours but it seems that after some time site session ends and it stops.

How to keep alive a page for 24 hours for all the times or how to avoid this timeout issue?

Comment: Are you saying the job does not run, or that it does run but is terminated before finishing? Where does the 'session' come into this all?

Comment: did my answer help you to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase Session Idle Time-out from

> IIS=>Application Pool=>Advanced setting

Increse time in required minutes. For your case change `Idle Time-out(minutes)` from 20 to 1440
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find yout answer in the following internal link:

[How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config)

or:

[Best way to modify session timeout for some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454957/best-way-to-modify-session-timeout-for-some-pages)